# How to make user created function from GUI into a matlab function that accepts parameters using Symbolic Toolbox

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am making a GUI where it needs to get the function that the user has entered in an editText and then plot it.

If the user enters `x .* sin(x)+13` then I must make that into a function that receives the values of `x` and then plot it and I have to use the `sym` from symbolic toolbox.

Comment: Why do you need to use `sym`?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a string to an anonymous function using `str2func`. You will need to add the `@(x)` 'prefix' to let function know that `x` is an input:

```
fun_str = 'x.*sin(x)+13';
fun = str2func(['@(x)' fun_str]);

x = 0:0.1:10;
y = fun(x)

plot(x,y)
```